# Nativescript sidekick latest update ( Version: 1.14.1-v.2018.11.23.3 (latest) )

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

I have just updated sidekick( or he did because i turned my mac off, and when i returned the sidekick updates automatically) and since this, i have been experiencing a lot of problems that i didn´t have for example this morning...**he simply get´s stuck on the "Refreshing application on device..."** and does nothing else...a few minutes ago was asking me to do it manually( which i didn´t had to do before) but if after that i update something on my code, then he get´s stuck...i´m bulding locally and i´m using my iphone 6´s.

Could anyone please tell me what is going on?!?!

Regards

Comment: In case anyone is having the same problem, i needed to update my xcode and also some ohter updates on my mac, after that everything is working just as before. Regards